# NAA flag declined for answer that repeats the question content

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50669971/4415734) as it includes almost identical phrasing as the image supplied in the question, with zero extra information that could be interpreted as an answer to the actual question.

My flag was declined with the message:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

What would be the reason for keeping this answer?

Comment: That literally *is* the answer to the question. The fact that the answer was included in an image in the question body doesn't make it any less an answer. If you don't think the answer is useful, then downvote it.

Comment: @CodyGray The question is asking for clarification of that slide's content, so that most certainly could *not* be the answer, despite it being factually correct. I downvoted as was recommended but I'm still not sure I fully understand how NAA works; it's clear I need to do some more reading.

Comment: I disagree; it’s not clear to me that the asker has even *read* the information on the slide. They certainly pay no lip service to it in the question. Regardless, NAA flags aren’t as complicated as everyone makes them. There’s been gallons of ink spilled over them on Meta, but the key is, don’t assume that moderators process them with any technical knowledge. They need to be obviously irrelevant to the question, either because they aren’t even in the form of an answer, or because they are talking about something clearly different (e.g., Python answer to a question tagged [c]).

Comment: @CodyGray OK, thanks for your assistance on this. I'll be more cautious with my flagging in future.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't want to make another post, but I just flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50948394/4415734) for the reason you just told me I could (answer in a totally different language) and it got declined... Any ideas?

Comment: Not all moderators are created equal, I guess. There are some who interpret the flag as meaning "not an answer to any conceivable question". I think that's ridiculous. I've deleted it now.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts:

- I think that the meat of the question, "[What is the benefit to having a header node and a trailer node in a linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50669861/1364007) is (emphasis mine):

  > Now I have seen another implementation of the Linked List, where there is a dummy node before the front of the list and a dummy node at the end of the list. **I do not see why we need these dummy nodes.**
- [The answer you flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50669971/1364007) says:

  > These two nodes, header and trailer, serve merely to simplify the insertion and deletion algorithms and are not part of the actual list.
  >
  > The actual list is between these two nodes.
- The guidance text for the Not An Answer flag is

  > This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

I would say that it was an attempt to answer the question. It answers the title (Q: What is the benefit...? A: It simplifies the insertion and deletion algorithms...). It answers the part of the question I quoted above which I take to be the main point of the question. The fact that it rephrases what is already in the image in the question is immaterial.

BTW - from [the timeline for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50669971/timeline) I can see [the review for your flag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23054421) was invalidated for reasons unknown (perhaps a moderator intervened?).

---

It might help to understand the thought processes of whoever is handing your flag in the review queue.

The question [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1364007) by [Undo ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo) deals with the other end of your question, i.e.: when should a question already flagged as Very Low Quality (VLQ) or Not An Answer (NAA) should actually be deleted and when it should be kept.

> [What] we should and shouldn't be deleting in review:
>
> [image: from Undo's question]
>
> What I'd like to focus on here is low quality and "wrong" answers. This is where I see the biggest issue.
>
> - **Low quality answers**. Yes, I know the queue is named "low quality posts", but not every minor problem needs to be deleted. Consider first if you can edit - or leave a comment for the author asking for more details, a better explanation, etc. **Only if you can't plausibly imagine anyone putting in the work to fix the post should you opt to delete these kinds of answers.**
>
>   For example, an answer might not have description for why the code works, but it still shouldn't be deleted; just leave a comment asking the author for an explanation, and move on.
> - **Wrong answers**: [Reviews like] [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14872753) [are] what really gets me.
>
>   This *does* attempt to answer the question. It may be *plain wrong* — but that's something for downvotes and comments to decide. Not deletion. This is why we have the voting system — if something is wrong, it should float to the bottom below all the other not-wrong things. This is the system working.

---

Also relevant is [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/1364007) in the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), which says in [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1364007):

> ## What NOT To Flag
>
> **Any post that attempts to answer the question—however badly—is still an answer**! Do not use the "not an answer" flag for *wrong* answers. Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers.
>
> You can downvote such answers as a signal that they are bad answers and not useful, but they are *still answers*, so you should not flag them.

Comment: You are correct that if you ignore the content of the question and only look at the title, the answer appears to answer it, however it is painfully clear that no attempt was made to answer the question in the context of the question content. The OP is essentially looking for an explanation of that slide image, and the answer simply repeated it (almost word for word). Is "How is the above method more simplified?" answered? No. You quoted a part of the question which you believe to be the main question, I would have to disagree; it doesn't even have a question mark.

Comment: Looking at [the timeline for the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50669861/timeline) we can see that both answers were provided when the question was in its [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50669861/1) - which doesn't contain any question marks in the body at all. It answered the question (badly, I admit) in the state that it was in when the answer was posted.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that it was revised after the answer was made, although I still struggle to see how it is an answer (by definition can repetition of the question be an answer?). Regardless, if you're happy that downvoting it is the correct action to take then I'm happy to go with that.

Comment: I would definitely say that it's not NAA. If you want it gone you can (a) downvote it (I assume you were one of the two downvoters), or (b) raise a custom moderator flag (but I suspect that'd be declined for similar reasons), or (c) comment on the answer and ask the answerer to delete it (unlikely). Like me you're gaining reputation quite slowly; it doesn't look like either of us will get the privilege to cast delete votes ([at 20k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)) any time soon.

Comment: Yes, the flag was declined by a moderator. A second NAA flag on the same answer by another user was declined by a second moderator. It is *at least* an attempt to answer the question, if not *the* answer to the question. "I do not think this answer is very good" is not a reason to flag an answer for deletion. It is, however, a reason to downvote.